# Ylabel rescale range and end at 0%

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 1000

x = np.arange(0, n)
y1 = np.random.normal(50, 4, n)
y2 = np.random.normal(25, 2.5, n)
y3 = np.random.normal(10, 1.1, n)

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 1)
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'royalblue')
ax1.set(xticks = [], title = 'Title')
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'darkorange')
ax2.set(xticks = [])
ax3.plot(x, y3, 'forestgreen')
ax3.set(xlabel = 'Random sample')
fig.legend(['First', 'Second', 'Third'])

plt.show()
```

I would like the `ylabels` to be shown in percentage, start at 0% and decrease. For example the blue one should go from `[30, 40, 50, 60, 70]` to `[-57.1%, -42.9%, -28.6%, -14.3%, 0%]`. The yellow one should go from `[10, 20, 30, 40]` to `[-75%, -50%, -25%, 0%]` and the green one should go from `[5, 7.5, 10, 12.5, 15]` to `[-66.6%, -50%, -33.3%, -16.7%, 0%]`.

The rest of the graphs should look exactly the same, only the `ylabels` should change.

[image]

Comment: You explained so much text in your question. The posted answer didn't fulfill your need. As a result you had to edit your question with **more text**. This is what happens when you don't explain your problem clearly enough. Even now your problem is unclear. You would do yourself and the readers a **big favor** if you additionally include a hand drawn sketch of your **desired final figure**. Otherwise, you will just keep clearing misunderstandings with the people answering your obscure question.

Comment: Hey, sorry for being unclear. I usually see people get criticized for not explaining enough, so I might have overdone it. I revamped the question to make it easier to understand what I'm after, I didn't include what I've tried and failed at this time to make the text more compact.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert your current yticks to floats and change to the range you want them to be at before displaying:

```py
import numpy as np

ticks = [float(x) for x in yvals]
ticks = np.array(ticks) - max(ticks)
yticklabels = ['{0:.1%}'.format(x) for x in ticks]
```

Do this for each plot separately.

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out! Your solution did indeed solve what I was describing (which is why I gave you a +1), but I need a solution that is a bit different. I tried explaining it better now in my 2nd edit, if it's still unclear please tell me and I will try and explain better :)